# jquery mobile, programmatically change page and open panel once landed

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4 and I would like to create a button that sends the user to another page, and opens the panel on this new page once landed :

I am trying this :

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#faq-page', function(){
    $('#faqcontactus').on("tap", function() {
        $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#welcome-page", { transition: "fade" });
        $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).find('#mypanel').panel("open");
    });
});
```

which goes to the page, opens the panel, but closes it instantly.

Can you help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it after you initiate page change process. That process is asynchronous and  pane open will not wait for this function to end. What you need to do is wait for next page to became visible, then you should trigger panel.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage');
    var activePageId = activePage .attr('id')
    if(activePageId === 'welcome-page') {
        activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until page is fully loaded before you open the panel, i.e. use `pagecontainershow`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
   var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
   if(activePage[0].id == "welcome-page") {
      $(".ui-panel", activePage).panel("open");
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Omar, thank you. I get an error activePage is not defined with your code. But it's ok because Gajotres' code works.

Comment: `var activePAge` capital `A` was the problem @Louis